# Is Rhythmbox visualization plugin dead? Plugin installed but no visuals

Tags: 16.04, rhythmbox, visualization

I've installed the plugin on Ubuntu 16.04, but using it with Rhythmbox shows just a blank section in the window. Not sure if there's something I'm supposed to activate or if this is broken.

When I right-click in the Visual Effects Window after clicking on it in the Rhythmbox window, the program hangs and prevents me from doing anything else on my machine.

If I'm playing music it will continue to play, my status bar will continue to update the time and show my CPU, memory, and network monitors, but I can't successfully click on anything or get a response from the keyboard in terms of switching to a different window, opening a terminal, etc.

Comment: Please, edit your question to include a link to the plugin you used.

Comment: I have this problem on Ubuntu 17.10 too.